# Why some of the negative voted answers are shown like hidden?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Why some of the negative voted answers are shown like hidden in SO as shown in figure? If we flag that answers then it getting declined also. If its a wrong answer why it cant just deleted from there?

[image]

Comment: Please do not flag wrong answers, downvote them instead.

Comment: Answers with score of `-3` and lower show up _hidden_.

Comment: @Yannis..Ok. But tell me why the answers shown like this?

Comment: @Nitin It's just a visual way to tell you the answer is most probably wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If its a wrong answer why it cant just deleted from there?

Because it can be corrected anytime by the original poster. Till then you just downvote and not flag it. We don't want to delete any post unless it is totally off-topic, spam, offensive etc.

Color change is based on the current UI implementation, so that answer having a score of -3 or more are displayed in a gray shade.